# Text Classification with Custom Vocabulary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, text-classification

I have some list of words/lexicon and I want to use them for a `BOW` classification. In `sklearn`it is possible to use `countvectorizer` and `tfidfvectorizer` in `sklearn`, the two approaches builds the vocabulary the use from the training data. But in my case I have built a kind of list of words(dictionary) that can be used to discriminate between the classes for text classification.

Is there any library or package I can use in python?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `vocabulary` parameter of the `CountVectorizer` here in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer).

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian', 'comp.graphics', 'sci.med'], shuffle=True, random_state=42)

my_vocabulary = ['aristotle',
 'arithmetic',
 'arizona',
 'arkansas'
]

count_vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=my_vocabulary)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X_train_counts)
```

And you will see in the output only that only the words from your vocabulary are used:

```py
Out[16]:
      0  1  2  3
0     0  0  0  0
1     0  0  0  0
2     0  0  0  0
3     0  0  0  0
4     0  0  0  0
...  .. .. .. ..
2252  0  0  0  0
2253  0  0  0  0
2254  0  0  0  0
2255  0  0  0  0
2256  0  0  0  0

[2257 rows x 4 columns]
```